# install additional python package on docker

Tags: docker, installation, jupyter

I have anaconda installed in my laptop and usually the way that I used to install additional python package is the following:  for example, I open my `Anaconda prompt`, which looks like a terminal, then I type the following code to download a package

```
git clone https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization.git
cd BayesianOptimization
python setup.py install
```

Then I open the jupyer notebook and in a cell I type `!pip install bayesian-optimization`, then the package is installed. I can go back to `Anaconda prompt` and type `conda list`, it displays

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Anaconda3:
bayesian-optimizaition    0.4.0
```

Now, I recently start to use `docker`. I've installed jupyer also in docker, but I found that it does not have access to this python package that I have installed and running properly if I just launch the jupyter via my laptop's Anaconda rather than launch jupyer in the docker. I think it is because of the environment issue? Also, I found that when I lauch jupyter from my laptop's Anaconda and docker, they point to different folders in my laptop. Should I make them point to the same folder to resolve this problem of using an installed package? and how to do that?

My current stupid method of solving this problem is: I launched the jupyer from docker and in the jupyer, I can open a `terminal` and in that, I type the previous command, and it downloads that package again and put it into the folder in my laptop that belongs to the jupyer launched in the docker, then I type `!pip ...` in a cell of jupyer, then everything works **except that** when I go back to the `terminal` in the jupyer launched in docker and type `conda list`, the `bayesian-optimizaition` does not show up in

```
jovyan@b67f312e292:~/work$
```

But I expect it should show up, as I just installed it, and it runs properly now in the jupyer launched in docker.

Can some one provide an explanation to this? Also, I really hope that I can avoid downloading the same package twice. How to just install the package once and make both jupyters (one launched without docker and one launched with docker) able to use that package, as I am planning to install some other packages that requires first to build a C++ solution. I've successfully make it work for the jupyter not launched from docker. I am on windows7 64bit system.

Comment: add a reproducer, the `docker run`commands, the Dockerfile used, `docker ps` and so

Comment: @user2915097 could you please elaborate a little bit? I have very limited knowledge about docker and learning it hard. Should I go to the docker window to type docker run? that will change the path?

Comment: what OS is your host running? A reproducer is the smallest code that shows the problem. Yes type those commands in a terminal, and paste it here

Comment: Yea, please modify your question to reproduce the steps with commands. It is really unclear what you are actually doing and trying to accomplish.